# UIButtons at the bottom of a loaded UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView on the bottom of a UITableView:

```
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:webview];
```

I need to add some buttons at the end of the UIWebView. The height of the UIWebView isn’t constant. If I do something like

```
[webview addSubview:button];
```

The button will overlap the webview, since the coordinates of the button's frame are based on the beginning of the UIWebView.
I thought about defining the button’s frame after finishing load the UIWebView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, webView.bounds.size.height, 280, 21);
```

But the problem is that I also have some data in the UITableView and it’s height isn’t constant. Of course I could keep the height of the UITableView in a variable while I’m building it, but I think that’s a very ugly solution.
I also thought about having 2 footers in the UITableView, but it doesn’t look like it is possible...
Just in case it is relevant, the UIWebView loads a HTML string before the buttons are added.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you thought of having two footer views. Obviously `UITableView` doesn't support that. But what you can do is create a custom `UIView` to contain the `UIWebView` and the buttons, e.g.:

```
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|         web view         |
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
| [button]        [button] |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

And then set that as the tableview's footer view.

Comment: I'm trying this solution (programmatically, without IB). The button appears properly, but the UIWebView doesn't. Shouldn't I simply have to do this, after UIView alloc? [viewA addSubview:self.webViewContent];
    [viewA addSubview:button];

Comment: What's your webview's `frame`?

Comment: CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 280, 400); But the size varies because I'm loading a html string with a changeable size. The strange thing is that if I add the webview as a footer, it works. If I add the webview to the custom view and then add the custom view as a footer, I get everything except the webview. This means the button is appearing after a blank space, where the webview should be.

Comment: I posted a new question in order to explain better what am I doing, since the content is getting a bit out of the original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075055/uiwebview-inside-uiview-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You could add the buttons at the end of the HTML content, assign them an href, and then use the technique described [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/files/NickDalton_360iDev_Sept2009.pdf) to intercept the click (look at the JavaScript callback section, where it explains how to "Call your Objective-C code from JavaScript in the UIWebView".

The idea is defining a proper `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` selector in your `UIWebView`'s delegate. This would be triggered by any operation done in the UIWebView which would produce the loading of a new page.

In that selector, you would dismiss the loading (by returning NO) and could do whatever ObjC processing you like, like the one you describe in your comment.

Example: your button could be

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:'button_1/YOU_URL">
    Click Me!
</button>
```

clicking on that button, the `webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` would be called where you would do:

```
NSURL *url = [request URL];
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"button_1"]) {
   <DO YOUR PROCESSING HERE>
   return NO;
}
```

(don't forget to return YES at the very end of the selector in case no button was clicked)

By the way, this PDF is really very interesting reading if you plan to heavily use UIWebView in your iOS apps.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want a simple link. When clicking on the button, I want to make a HTTP Get request (using ASIHTTPRequest) and then load the response in another UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, it was already useful. I think the code will be easier to maintain if I can just add a custom subview. I'll keep your solution in mind, in case I don't manage to add the custom subview.