# UIWebView inside UIView programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiwebview

I have a `UITableView` and I want to add a `UIView` as a footer. This `UIView` has a `UIWebView` and a `UIButton`. I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 280, 400);
self.webViewContent = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.webViewContent.delegate = self;
self.webViewContent.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(webView.bounds.origin.x, webView.bounds.origin.y, webView.bounds.size.width+20, webView.bounds.size.height + firstFrameY)];
viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[viewA addSubview:self.webViewContent];
[viewA addSubview:linkButton];

[self.emailDetailsTableView setTableFooterView:viewA];
}
```

The output is that I can see everything except the `UIWebView`.
However, if I test the following code

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(webView.bounds.origin.x, webView.bounds.origin.y, webView.bounds.size.width+20, webView.bounds.size.height + firstFrameY)];
viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
//[viewA addSubview:self.webViewContent];
[viewA addSubview:linkButton];

[self.emailDetailsTableView setTableFooterView:self.webViewContent];
}
```

I can see the `UIWebView`. Please note that I commented the line where I was adding the `UIWebView` to the `UIView`. If I uncomment the line, I don't see the `UIWebView`!!!

Any ideas concerning what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where the UIWebView is created?  it must be getting added to another view somewhere.

Comment: You're adding the footer using - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section, right?

Comment: are `self.webViewContent` and `webView` in the first piece of code same?

Comment: I've added to the question the code where the UIWebView is created. I'm adding the footer to the table view using setTableFooterView, as you can see in the code. I'm not using viewForFooterInSection. self.webViewContent and webView contain the same information, although they are different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your UIWebView is already on screen somewhere. Indeed, if the webView is not displayed, its HTML is not rendered (like in off-screen rendering) and the `webViewDidFinishLoading` never called.

What I would try and do in your case is adding the `viewA` to the table footer and make the button hidden, if you need to show it only *after* the webView has loaded.

If you don't want the webView to occupy a large space in the footer while it is loading, make viewA small in the first place. When the HTML has loaded, change the view size (possibly according to the web page height, if it is ok for your app).

just a suggestion...